# Adventure game in a forest

Tags: python, adventure-game

I've started writing a game and I need help, because I know there are many ways to improve what I am doing. I am doing it the basic way I know I can but I know there is more complex ways of doing it.

```
import time
print"Created on 3/12/2013"
print"ver 1.2"
print"Created by: Daniel Vargas"
print'At any point type "help" for commands'
print"===== Hello ====="
print"Welcome to ZOTD3000!"
time.sleep(2)
print("To find your fate")
###         This is the first Fate        ###
while True:
    fate = raw_input('Write A, B, or C:\n')
    if fate == 'A':
        print"You have selected choice A"
        time.sleep(2)
        break
    elif fate == 'help':
        print"You can only type A, B, or C."
    else:
        print"You can only type A, B, or C."
        time.sleep(2)
###         Here is the first decision          ###
###         From  Fate A            ###
def Forest(Health,Hunger,Inventory):
    print'You wake up in the middle of the forest'
    Inventory = 'Inventory: '
    Squirrel =  'Squirrel'
    while True:
        Choice1 = raw_input('You...\n')
        if Choice1 in ('Life', 'life'):
            print('Health: '+str(Health))
            print('Hunger: '+str(Hunger))
        elif Choice1 in ('Look',  'look'):
            print 'You see many trees, and what looks like an edible dead Squirrel, \na waterfall to the north and a village to the south.'
        elif Choice1 in ('Pickup', 'pickup'):
            p1 = raw_input('Pickup what?\n')
            if p1 == Squirrel:
                if Inventory == 'Inventory: ':
                    print'You picked up a Squirrel!'
                    Inventory = Inventory + Squirrel + ', '
                elif Inventory == 'Inventory: Squirrel, ':
                        print'You already picked that up!'
            else:
                print"You can't find a "+str(p1)+"."
        elif Choice1 in ('Inventory', 'inventory'):
            print Inventory
        elif Choice1 in ('Eat', 'eat'):
            print Inventory
            e1 = raw_input('Eat what?\n')
            if e1 == Squirrel:
                while True:
                    if Inventory == 'Inventory: ':
                        print("You don't have one.")
                        break
                    else:
                        print("It taste's funny. You feel sick.")
                        print("Your health is lowered. But your not hungry.")
                        Health = Health - 1
                        Hunger = Hunger + 1
                        Inventory = 'Inventory: '
                        break
            else:
                print"You don't have a "+str(e1)+"."
        elif Choice1 in ('Kill', 'kill'):
            print'There is nothing to kill.'
        elif Choice1 in ('Goto', 'goto'):
            print"There isn't a place you can Goto in sight."
        elif Choice1 in ('North', 'north'):
            print('Heading North!')
            Waterfall(Health,Hunger,Inventory)
            break
        elif Choice1 in ('East', 'east'):
            print('Heading East!')
            Desert(Health,Hunger)
            break
        elif Choice1 in ('South', 'south'):
            print('Heading South!')
            Village(Health,Hunger)
            break
        elif Choice1 in ('West', 'west'):
            print('Heading West!')
            Forest2(Health,Hunger)
            break
        elif Choice1 in ('help', 'Help'):
            print('You can type Inventory, Life, North, East, South, West, Look, Pickup, Eat, Kill, Goto.')
        else:
            print"You can't do that! Remember CaSe SeNsItIvE!\n Type"' "help" for commands.'
def Waterfall(Health,Hunger,Inventory):
    while True:
        Choice2 = raw_input('You...\n')
        if Choice2 in ('help', 'Help'):
                print('You can type Inventory, Life, North, East, South, West, Look, Pickup, Eat, Kill, Goto.')
        elif Choice2 in ('Life', 'life'):
            print('Health: '+str(Health))
            print('Hunger: '+str(Hunger))
        elif Choice2 in ('North', 'north'):
            print("You can't go up the waterfall!")
        elif Choice2 in ('South', 'south'):
            print('Heading South!')
            Forest(Health,Hunger,Inventory)
            break
        elif Choice2 in ('East', 'east'):
            print('Heading East!')
            Desert(Health,Hunger)
            break
        elif Choice2 in ('West', 'west'):
            print('Heading West!')
            Hills(Health,Hunger)
            break
        elif Choice2 in ('Inventory', 'inventory'):
            print Inventory
        else:
            print"You can't do that! Remember CaSe SeNsItIvE!\n Type"' "help" for commands.'
###         From Fate B             ###
###         From Fate C             ###
###         Main            ###
def main():
    Inventory = 'Inventory: '
    if fate == 'A':
        Forest(10,10,Inventory)


main()
```

Answer (score 4):

The existing code is not easy to maintain. If you want to add new places or new actions you will have to write a lot of very specific and deeply nested code.

I've never written a game like this, but it's a good case for modelling with classes. You have a `Place`, which *has* a set of `neighbours` which are also `Places`. You have a `Player` who *has* an `inventory` which *contains* `Items`. The `Player` has a level of `health` and `hunger` which can be modified by `Items` in his inventory. An `Item` can be a medicine, a source of food, a physical object, etc.

To illustrate one aspect of this, I would consider something like:

```
class Place(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbours = {"North": None,
                           "South" : None
                           "East" : None
                           "West" : None}

    def add_neighbour(self, direction, neighbour):
        self.neighbours[direction] = neighbour

    def leave(self):
        # this is maybe one way to handle movement
        # if the player stores a reference to their location
        # but by no means the only way or the best way

        # get direction from user
        return self.neighbours[direction]
```

Which will allow you to set up your world separately like:

```
Waterfall = Place("Waterfall")
Forest = Place("Forest")
Waterfall.add_neighbour("South", Forest)
```

Your character could look something like (as a starting point)

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, initial_location=None):
        self.name = name
        self.inventory = []
        self.location = initial_location
        self.health = 100
        self.hunger = 0
```

There are ways to make the direction choices robust, for example making sure that a's southern neighbour is b's northern neighbour and so on, but hopefully this gives you a general sense of what I am talking about. Eventually you will get a feel for what the entities in your code *are* and what they *do* and how they interact.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some small fixes:

- **Make the input lowercase.** By replacing `Choice2 = raw_input('You...\n')` with `Choice2 = raw_input('You...\n').lower()` you can replace `Choice1 in ('East', 'east')` by `Choice1 == 'east'`.
- **Making the inventory a list.** Create it with `Inventory = []`, adding a item would be `Inventory += ['squirrel'])` and printing the inventory would be `print 'Inventory:' + ', '.join(inventory)`.

You can also return the state and the next place in the functions, like this:

```
def forest(health, hunger, inventory, here=['squirrel']):
    place = forest
    choice = raw_input("Forest: ").lower()
    if choice == "house":
        place = house
    elif choice in here:
        inventory += [choice]
        here.remove(choice)
    elif choice == "eat":
        choice = raw_input("Eat what? ").lower()
        if choice in inventory:
            if choice == "squirrel":
                inventory.remove(choice)
                health -= 50
                hunger -= 50
        else:
            print "You don't have %s." % choice
    else:
        print "Err, what?"
    return (place, health, hunger, inventory))

def house(health, hunger, inventory):
    print "You won!"
    exit(0)

def main():
    place, health, hunger, inventory = forest, 100, 0, []
    while true:
        if hunger >= 100:
            health -= 10
        if health <= 0: 
            print "You die!"
            break
        hunger += 10

        place, health, hunger, inventory = place(health, hunger, inventory)

main()
```

Comment: I know what you meant by
Choice2 = raw_input('You...\n').lower()
but I like having it as it is it helps my eyes.

Comment: But the inventory thing I like and will use thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried it out the way you had it and I got confused?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to follow propeller's suggestion of converting input to lowercase, you can do this instead:

```
Choice1 = raw_input('You...\n').capitalize()
if Choice1 == 'Life':
```

This will also accept eg. 'LIFE'. It is easier to maintain than `if Choice1 in ('Life', 'life'):`

Comment: You mean `Choice1 = raw_input('You...\n').capitalize()`  (which is robuster, by turning `LIFE` to `Life` as well).

Comment: @JohnOptionalSmith Thanks, I'd forgotten about `capitalize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the game has you traveling, you might want to store your locations in a 2d arrray of functions:

```
map  = [[Forest , Forest2  , Hills], 
        [Forest2, Waterfall, Village], 
        [Hills  , Waterfall, House]]
```

From this type of approach (white space might not be correctly, not a Python expert), you can programatically derive the directions you can go.

You could even create an items map, to place the squirel and other stuff

```
items  = [[""          , "Squirrel", ""], 
          ["Squirrel"  , ""        , ""], 
          [""          , ""        , ""]]
```

Which would place then squirrels only in Forest2 locations.